# What are reducing sugars?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I found that from many definitions reducing sugars are those which contain free aldehyde or ketone group which can reduce reagent like Tollen's Reagent.But I have also read that ketones get oxidized **only** with very strong oxidizing agents like alkaline KMnO4 or acidified potassium dichromate under vigorous condition.So according to what i read,then i could say that fructose is a non reducing sugar as it won't be able to reduce weak oxidizing agents like Tollen's Reagent.

But its also said in my textbook that all monosaccharides are reducing sugars.But fructose is a monosaccharide.Then how can it be a reducing sugar.Please explain me if there is any misconceptions from my side.

Comment: Not a duplicate per se, but the answer is there nonethelss

Comment: I din't see that question when i typed it SE should work upon this.

Comment: It's more tricky example, but if Community marked it then who knows... Still, searching for dupes may be AI complete ;)

Comment: @Mithoron  i agree with that.Somebody must develop an efficient AI :-p.

Comment: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3071/searching-guidelines-for-newbie